# which cloud service is appropriate for a multi user ms access application?

Tags: ms-access, cloud, remote-access, multi-user

I build a multi user database application for my client using a split ms access database. The number of users won't exceed 5. The back-end file should be stored on some server where as each user will have a version of the front-end on his local machine. The front-ends will be linked to the back-end file on the server.

My client does not want to own and manage a server so he booked a cloud service. The cloud service has to create local versions of the back-end file on each user's machine that are synchronized permanently. This is not the desired behaviour since it results to data conflicts all the time. Is there some cloud service that would allow to link a local ms access db to a shared ms access db without synchronization?
Ideally, the frontend-users will have access to the back-end file only via the front-end but not via the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. That cloud service won't work.

Either use a hosted SQL Server (service) like *Azure SQL*, or the upcoming *Dataverse Connector*:

[Microsoft 365 roadmap for Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Access)

Comment: use Remote Desktop Protocol...there are hosting companies providing this.  RDP is the standard method to deploy Access (or any Windows app) to geographically separated users.